# SceneKit – How does the option impulse works for the method applyForce?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnnode

When applying a force on a dynamic body, it seems that this force won't be persistent even if impulse is set at `false`.

I have a sphereNode with a physicsBody : dynamic, mass=1 and damping=0. World gravity is set at (0,0,0).

If I apply a force in a gesture recognizer :

```
func Detected(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        sphereNode.physicsBody!.applyForce(SCNVector3Make(1, 0, 0), impulse: false)
    }

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        sphereNode.physicsBody!.clearAllForces()     
    }
}
```

Then the velocity goes to `0.0166` as if the force was applied only during one frame and stay constant unless I trigger the gesture again.

The only way to make it work as a true constant force is to call applyforce in the renderer loop but then the only difference with the non-impulse applyforce is a factor of 60. I don't think that is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is how it's supposed to work.

You use an impulse when you want to instantaneously change a body's momentum. For example, you might use impulse to fire a ball from a cannon. Like a cannon, it's "fire and forget"; you call the method and the ball flies off until it hits something.

You use a force (`impulse:NO`) when *you want to make a continuous effect*. That is, it doesn't cause a continuous effect (otherwise there'd have to be API for enumerating and canceling individual continuous forces on each body), but it gives you a tool to use when you want to do something on every frame to create a continuous effect.

For example, you'd use a force if you want your spaceship to accelerate when you press a button, and keep accelerating until you release it. While the button is held down, just call `applyForce` every time your `update` method runs.

The `impulse` toggle does two things for the two cases:

- As you've noticed, it changes the units of magnitude to be appropriate for each case.
- When using `impulse:NO`, it delays evaluation until the end of the current frame cycle. So you can apply several different forces during one `update`, and when SceneKit simulated physics for the next frame, it'll apply the sum of the forces (unless you call `clearAllForces` first).

Comment: Thank you, this very last case is exactly what I was looking for (a reason for this option to exist)